# Recording audio with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have created something like MPD pad in javascript. And now I want to record sequences. I have tried to record all the keyups and keydowns, then duplicate existing layer of audio elements and then play them in the background according to recorded inputs. But is there any sound recording API to record output sound of browser so I could have a the sequence recorded into audio file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how it's implemented. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/